# Streaming from android Camera to Ionic

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-camera

I am using a similar version of the code of [Peepers](https://github.com/foxdog-studios/peepers) to stream from the native `android.hardware.Camera` to http port, and then displaying it in Ionic, so instead of just running the Peepers app I put the code in an Android service.

Even though the feed seems really slow, it does work for some time, then suddenly does not anymore. I can't see anything odd in logcat, and in Chrome debugging it only says `GET http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

The main requirement is that I need to do some processing of the Camera stream in a service (since it can be shared among apps), is there a better way to stream the Camera feed to Ionic apps? maybe using native code and cordova plugin

Comment: How long does it take until you get that error? Is it a consistent amount of time or does it vary?

Comment: Which plugin are you using ? Is it this one? https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

Comment: @Stallion no as said in the question it is from a pure Android service to Ionic webview. The library used in the service is Peepers, in Ionic/cordova I just use `<img src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/"/>` as it is shown here: https://github.com/foxdog-studios/peepers#client-test-page

Comment: @SteelToe good question, I don't know, I didnt time it. What would it mean?

Comment: I think it might mean a good old fashioned time out, the way to prove it would be to see if the time it takes for the error to occur is consistent, if it is then that is probaly the cause and the best move would be to program it to reset the connection and stream every time the amount of time it takes for the error to occur passes

Comment: I think the best would be to know where it comes from instead of patching the problem. I let it run for a while but I didnt see it time out as it took at least a few hours, I can't really wait that long just staring at it